# Xamarin forms C#, сохранить изменения

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

У меня есть label, который после нажатия на кнопку изменяет цвет на красный. После выхода из приложения label меняется на прежний. Как сохранить изменения цвета label после завершения приложения?

Предлагаю конечный результат, может кому-то пригодится!
Скачиваете через `NuGet` пакет `Xam.Plugins.Settings`.

```
Label label_1 = new Label
{Text = ""};
stackLayout.Children.Add(label_1);

TapGestureRecognizer tapGesture_1 = new TapGestureRecognizer
{NumberOfTapsRequired = 1};

tapGesture_1.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
{
    label_1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    label_1.TextColor = Color.White;

    bool value = true;
    CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue<bool>("name_1", value);
};

label_1.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture_1);

if (CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("name_1"))
{
    label_1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Работает и после закрытия программы

Comment: Сохранить это значение в файл/настройки и в дальнейшем при запуске проверять, есть ли этот файл, если есть - берем значение от туда.

Comment: Пишет не удается преобразовать object в Xamarin.Forms.Color protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            if (App.Current.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out object name))
            {
                label_1.BackgroundColor = (object)name;
            }
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
 
        private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object value = label.BackgroundColor;
             
            App.Current.Properties["name"] = value;
        }

Comment: В вопрос это все добавляйте, под ним есть кнопка "править".

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: почему `(object )name;`, а не `(Color)name`? Да и вообще, почему сразу не хранить нужный объект в настройках?

Comment: Новичок в Xamarin, поэтому нашел такой пример с сохранением данных

Comment: Увидел свою ошибку, но теперь пишет не удается преобразовать Xamarin.Forms.Color в тип object. Изменил код в вопросе. Ругается на name

Comment: @max053 Если у вас фон кнопки меняется только на стандартный и красный цвет, то храните в настройках булевое значение, например `buttonIsRed` и по нему на загрузке выставляйте либо стандартный цвет, либо красный.

Comment: Всем спасибо! В вопросе выложил конечный результат

Comment: Лучше оформите нормальный ответ, убрав его из вопроса (и потом примите ответ).